# SELECT query in Dropwizard database healthcheck

Tags: database, hibernate, dropwizard, hibernate-native-query

Hello I am using dropwizard and hibernate in my application and have written the following heakthcheck. This gives me a

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.  error
```

I tried changing the `.getResultList()` call to `executeUpdate()` `getMaxResults()`, `list()` but none of them work. How can I make a SELECT query work in a healthcheck?

```
public class DatabaseHealthCheck extends HealthCheck {

  SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  private static final String validationQuery =
      "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mySchema'";

  public DatabaseHealthCheck(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }


  @Override
  protected Result check() throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    final Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
    try {

      EntityManager em = session.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
      em.createNativeQuery(validationQuery).getResultList();
      txn.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      txn.rollback();
      return Result.unhealthy("Cannot execute query due to " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      session.close();
    }
    return Result.healthy();
  }
}
```

I also tried making the query simpler - 'SELECT1 ' but still see the same error

Comment: I copied/pasted your code with `SELECT 1` as validation query and it worked on my side. BTW don't forget to put your session in a try-with-resources statement and instead of using an entity manager you could directly call `createNativeQuery` from your `session`